# Index entry with blackboard font in footnote ignored

Tags: footnotes, indexing, blackboard

The following MWE produces the expected index entries for Q and Z but none for N.  I guess this must be some strange interaction between `\footnote`, `\mathbb`, and `\index`, but how do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Some\index{Q@$\mathbb{Q}$} text.\footnote{Here we explain $\mathbb{N}$\index{N@$\mathbb{N}$} and Z.\index{Z@$Z$}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fourier` package does a “bad thing”™, namely

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\math@bb}{Ufutm}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\mathbb\math@bb}
```

Fix it.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{Ufutm}}


\begin{document}

Some\index{Q@$\mathbb{Q}$} text.\footnote{Here we explain $\mathbb{N}$\index{N@$\mathbb{N}$} and Z.\index{Z@$Z$}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

But beware that another call of `\index{N@$\mathbb{N}$}` not in a footnote might produce another entry in the index, so it's better to use

```
\index{N@$\string\mathbb{N}$}
```

when in a footnote.